# How to connect to a Node.js server that's using Express using an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

You run a `node.js` express server on LocalHost or a service provider (Heroku, AWS). How do I connect this to my website?

E.G -- You go to..
[www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com) -> Connects to HEROKU server -> HEROKU server sends html file

**app.js**

```
const http      = require('http'),
      path      = require('path'),
      express   = require('express'),
      app       = express(),
      serv      = require('http').Server(app);

var htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'client');

app.use(express.static(htmlPath));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(htmlPath + '/index.html');
});

var server = serv.listen(2000, () => {
    var host = 'localhost';
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log(`listening on http://${host}:${port}/`);
});
```

In this case, now instead of going to `localhost:2000` directly to receive the `index.html` file, you go to `yourdomain.com` and the server sends the `index.html` file

Comment: Take a look at the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) on how to host your application there.

Comment: I know how to deploy my app on hosting and connect to them. I'm specifically asking using the `express` method and using my own domain URL, instead of the one provided by them

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DNS system to redirect to the public IP of the machine hosting the Express application. The express application needs to also be listening for GET requests sent to the path you are specifying.

You would also need to configure the firewall on that machine to allow port 80 and 443 to be open.

Comment: I've tried this, but the process isn't smooth. Is there a more smooth way of doing this?

Comment: You can rearchitech the system a bit to use easier off the shelf services, such as lambda and S3 if you just want an simple website domain. I've created a deployable auto updating static site with that before you can reference: https://github.com/twosdai/contentGrabber

Otherwise unfortunantly if you want to have some express app running you'll need to run it in some compute system and then hook it up to a domain name, in AWS that would be done in Route 53.